# Batch File select specify file that created/modified by today date at Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I facing a problem when I run the following batch at Windows Server 2008, it will select those file of yesterday and today date but I just only want today. When I try testing this batch file at windows 7, it works fine, it will only copy today file.
So is it because of the Windows different or the code? Any advice??
My batch file code:
`robocopy "D:\Program Files\My LogFiles\JobServer_01" "D:\Program Files\My LogFiles\LogDestination" s*.txt /MAXAGE:1`

Comment: Are the clocks on the Server and the Win7 machine the same?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using vb script? 
it's much more simpler to handle operations based on date using vb & then calling the same vb script using a batch.

```
target="d:\path2\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "D:\path1"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    if (DateDiff("d",objFile.DateCreated, NOW)=<1) Then  
    objFSO.MoveFile objFile, target
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name & vbcrlf  
    end if
Next
```

Save the above code in .vbs file. replace the startfolder and target variables with desired folders. This will poll for any file that is created today and will copy it to destination folder.